# How to config Jetty to interpret correctly UTF-8 in filenames

Tags: character-encoding, jetty, filenames, exist-db

After upgrading to eXist-db 4.7.0, we have now Jetty 404 errors for filenames with UFT-8 accented or Chinese characters.
Any idea if there is a config file to manage that?

For eg.:

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /.../dicoEnviro-fr/humanit%C3%A9.xml.
Reason: Document /.../dicoEnviro-fr/humanité.xml not found
Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.14.v20181114
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jetty 9.4.20.v20190813 (there are updates to UTF-8 handling of resources on `java.nio.file.FileSystem` present since 9.4.16.v20190411 that you need)

*Since I don't know what eXist-db does to start Jetty, I'm going to assume it's embedded, and answer based on that assumption.*

Make sure your `ServletContextHandler` or `WebAppContext` is declared to use a Base Resource that is defined as a `PathResource` object pointing to your directory location defined as a `java.nio.file.Path` object.

Advice about Base Resource declaration:

- Do not use a `String` to define it, that winds up being a `URLResource` which works with URL references, not file system paths, and you'll have the problem you are experiencing.
- Do not use a `File` to define it, as that winds up being a `FileResource` which is deprecated functionality, and known to have problems with UTF-8 references.
- Ensure your `java.nio.file.Path` is an absolute path. (no relative paths)
- Ensure your `java.nio.file.Path` is normalized. (no `"//"` or `"/../"` segments)